# The system of linear equations has a solution and $x_1 \neq 0$, prove that columns of the matrix are linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

The system of linear equations:

$ \begin{bmatrix}
a_0 & a_1 & a_2 \\
a_1 & a_0 & a_1 \\
a_2 & a_1 & a_0 
\end{bmatrix}  $
$ \begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3 
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
0 
\end{bmatrix}  $

has a solution and $x_1 \neq 0$. Prove that columns of the coefficient matrix are linearly independent.

I've noted that any two columns are independent, also from the system we have the linear combination: $x_1 \begin{bmatrix}
a_0 \\
a_1 \\
a_2 
\end{bmatrix} + x_2 \begin{bmatrix}
a_1 \\
a_0 \\
a_1 
\end{bmatrix} + x_3\begin{bmatrix}
a_2 \\
a_1 \\
a_0 
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
0 
\end{bmatrix}$,

which is almost a linear combination equals $ \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
0 
\end{bmatrix}  $
, but $x_1 \neq 0$.

Comment: I think the key lies in the coefficients, they're not just any random one, and maybe somewhere we need to divide by $x_1$.

Comment: Could you restate the question to make it more clear that it is? An advice is to pose it with the words "Given SCENARIO, such that THESE CONDITIONS hold, than I WANT TO DISCOVER IF THIS HYPOTHESIS HOLDS TRUE"

Comment: @BrunoPeixoto Maybe the "ask a question" interface should include question templates.

Comment: Great idea! We should be in touch with SO staff.

Comment: From the given condition it follows that $a_0^2-a_1^2=1$, $a_1=0$ and $a_1^2-a_0a_2=0$, that is $a_0=\pm1$ and $a_1=a_2=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $A$ as your matrix of coefficients, and assume the columns of $A$ are *linearly dependent.*

If you set $v=(x_3,x_2,x_1)^T\in \mathbb{R}^3$ then you'll see that $Av=\vec{e}_3$ so $\text{Col}(A)$ is the $xz-$plane.

This is only possible if the second entry of every column of $A$ is $0$ i.e. $a_0=a_1=0$.

If $a_2$ also equals $0$ then $A\equiv O$ which is a contradiction to your assumption that $[A|e_1]$ is consistent.

If $a_2\neq 0$ then $[A|e_1]$ has solution set $(0,x,\frac{1}{a_2})^T:x \in \mathbb{R}$ which is another contradiction.